# Aligning flex items based on dynamic sizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I need to be able to align these timestamp flex items under each other and justified to the left but the content is dynamic so each flex item could be of different length as shown here:

[image]

```css
.history-section-title {
  display: flex;
}

.date-style {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="history-section-title">
    <nav aria-label="Breadcrumb">
      <ol>
        <li><a href="/app/homepage">Homepage</a></li>
        <li title="Campaign Targeting Government and State-owned Organizations in Asian Countries"><a href="/app/guid:710cdac51f5a66ea75f9674e26dc9c7c" class="bx--link">Campaign Targeting Government and State-owned Organizations in Asian Countries</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
    <div class="date-style">17 minutes ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="history-section-title">
    <nav aria-label="Breadcrumb">
      <ol>
        <li><a href="/app/homepage">Homepage</a></li>
        <li title="eBay Squatting Campaign"><a href="/app/fc154bf5-a5d1-5c33-ada0-e9a8167f909b">eBay Squatting Campaign</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
    <div class="date-style">3 hours ago</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like a table to me, why not use one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two pretty simple options to fix your problem.

The first one is to justify content inside of `flex` parent so the all unused space is between existing content. That way whenever content doesn't take up entire space, you will have empty space between breadcrumbs and time.

```
.history-section-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Another option is to make breadcrumbs take up all unused space. That way there will be no empty space between breadcrumbs and time.

```
.history-section-title {
    display: flex;
}

.Breadcrumb{
   flex: 1;
}
```

Also, you can remove this section for both options:

```
.date-style {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```